# What does happen inside this catch block?

Tags: java

I found this code online as a **password loop game**, it's working fine, but my question is: how?

What does happen in this **catch block** exactly?

I'm curious about this line specifically:

> reader.next();

```
boolean loop = true;
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("PIN: ");

    while (loop) {
        try {
            Integer Code = reader.nextInt();

            if (Code == 8273) {
                System.out.println("Access granted");
                loop = false;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Access denied");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid PIN!");
            reader.next();
        }
    }
```

Edit : of course I did deliberately input a Non-integer input to cause the exception.

Edit2 :
When I removed that line, the program kept printing Please enter a valid PIN! For ever.

Comment: I tried to change it to (reader.nextInt()) to understand, but it immediately threw another InputMismatchException,  but for what input?

Comment: Is there some sort of exception that is being thrown?

Comment: Yes When I enter a Non-integer value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, what the programmer really wanted here is to capture the next line of input, and verify whether that was a valid integer.

But the code is, admittedly, very confusing. And it relies on the fact that by default, when you "swallow" the next token with anything but `.nextLine()` with a `Scanner`, it relies on the current [delimiter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#delimiter--), which by default matches a newline.

Not good.

Here is a version which is more explicit:

```
String input;
int code;

while (true) {
    System.out.print("PIN: ");
    input = reader.nextLine();
    try {
        code = Integer.parseInt(input);
    } catch (NumberFormatException ignored) {
        // not an integer!
        System.out.println("Enter a valid PIN!");
        continue;
    }
    if (code == 8273)
        break;
    System.out.println("Access denied");
}

System.out.println("Access granted");
```

Comment: Sorry sir I didn't get that swallowing stuff :)

Comment: This has to do with inheritance; `Exception` is a superclass of `RuntimeException` which is itself a superclass of `NumberFormatException`. And `RuntimeException` and children are special in Java in the sense that they are _unchecked_ exceptions. Which means catching `Exception` is a very, very bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

If `nextInt` throws an exception (because the value entered isn't an `int`), then the `catch` block is entered. The last line of which,

```
reader.next(); // <-- discards invalid token.
```

Removes the invalid token and then the loop iterates.

Also, don't box the `Code`<sup>1</sup>

```
int code = reader.nextInt();
```

<sup>1<sub>Using an Object type and then testing equality with `==` is a **bad idea**™. Also, by convention Java variable names start with a lower case letter.</sub></sup>

Comment: Yeah well, the problem here is that `Exception` is caught, right? Which means it will also catch any `RuntimeException`... Including `NumberFormatException`. Anyway, the code in itself is really crude...

Comment: @fge Well, I suppose I really should change my bank card PIN.

Comment: Do you mean that this line replaces the line : Integer Code = reader.nextInt(); ?  thanks for your reply.

Comment: @mhashem6 Yes, because a) `Code` should be `code` and b) boxing an `int` to an `Integer` (`reader.nextInt()` returns an `int`) doesn't make sense with your code.

Comment: I copied it as I found it on a website (Android Authority) because I didn't know that this replacing-input stuff is possible in the catch block.

Answer (score 1):

The catch block simply catches the exception when anything other than an integer is entered. Since `Code` is an `Integer`, the input would have to be an integer. After catching the exception and printing the error, the reader moves to the next input until a proper value is entered, and the boolean `loop` becomes false, which ends the while loop at the end of the `if` statement once the correct value is entered.